# WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway

Tags: php, paypal, lang

This is with regards to the woocommerce/wordpress plugin. How can I force PayPal to use a particular language with code in functions.php? I have looked through a lot on internet, and also on the doc pages PayPal have. Only thing I can find, is that `locale` can be set, but no reference about where. And also docs say that its possible to set language in the settings page (nothing there) and that PayPal will use WP_lang to set language (doesn't happen).

Answer (score 0):

Which WooCommerce plugin are you using?

This newest one: https://woocommerce.com/woocommerce-and-paypal/

Is API-based, and much better than the "Standard" HTML redirect method that comes with many base WooCommerce installs, so I would recommend upgrading if you fancy it.

---

As far as setting a default locale parameter, it will depend on which plugin's integration method you are using.  There may be a setting for it in the plugin, or you may need to append an `lc` or `locale` variable if the feature isn't implemented by the plugin.

Typically setting a manual locale is not so necessary, though. The PayPal checkout will automatically detect the most appropriate setting based on the buyer's user agent language setting and GeoIP.

I'm not sure how exactly it all works, but that auto detection will sometimes be so strong as to override what you specify with `lc` or `locale`, making those parameters difficult to test, and not so meaningful to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Case is, that its the new plugin, and its set for US by default. I tried geoloaction also. Any tips to how apply that lc/locale setting manually?

Comment: Well looking at the WooCommerce code, it seems to be getting the value from `wp_localize_script()`: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/trunk/includes/class-wc-gateway-ppec-cart-handler.php#L494 , and putting that value in the call to the PayPal button: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/trunk/assets/js/wc-gateway-ppec-smart-payment-buttons.js#L70

What I would do its edit that last js file and just add a simple console.log() or alert() of `wc_ppec_context.locale`, or use Dev Tools console

Comment: Keep in mind that whether or not it is passing a locale will not necessarily change what is experienced. The browser language, IP geo location, and browser cookies with PayPal (i.e. the language of PayPal accounts you have logged into) can all matter more than what is passed as the locale.  So setting `locale` is not that important, and not something I recommend worrying about in general.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Well it affects user experience if PayPal is set to US by default. Because then the user have to manually change language and thus interface to Norwegian (in this case). Do you have a suggestion on what to put down in that last js file?

Comment: I can't go into detail of specific changes, but start by printing out the value so you know what's actually being set.  Another place `locale` can be set is in the <script> that loads the PayPal JS: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#locale , and I'm not sure if this plugin does that, so you could add it if not.  You can always hardcode things (use the string value `no_NO`) to set it, until you get it to work.  Just keep in mind during testing that your browser language, any PayPal.com cookies, and IP address may take precedence over whatever locale was passed

Comment: Can you show me the snippet? If you can learn me, I will learn the next one

Comment: Solved it:add_filter('woocommerce_paypal_express_checkout_paypal_locale','set_default_language_paypal_express');

function set_default_language_paypal_express()
{
    return 'no_NO';
}